# autopausing a video in the <object> tag

Tags: html, object, tags, param

How can I get the below code to automatically pause when I load the webpage it is in?

```
<object id="media1" height="568" type="video/x-ms-wmv" width="1000">
    <param name="filename" value="VideoSetup.wmv"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag in html5, for example .
Then you use JavaScript to get info from you video using getElementById("myVideo") then use if,else conditions to pause or play your video like myVideo.pause();